# Texture not being drawn on Screen

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to follow a slightly outdated tutorial on making a Tile Engine.

The problem is that the Texture I am trying to draw on screen, doesn't show up. I just get a black screen.

I've taken the most relevant parts of Engine.cpp:

```
bool Engine::Init()
{
    LoadTextures();
    window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800,600,32), "RPG");
    if(!window)
        return false;

    return true;
}

void Engine::LoadTextures()
{
    sf::Texture sprite;
    sprite.loadFromFile("C:\\Users\\Vipar\\Pictures\\sprite1.png");
    textureManager.AddTexture(sprite);
    testTile = new Tile(textureManager.GetTexture(0));
}

void Engine::RenderFrame()
{
    window->clear();
    testTile->Draw(0,0,window);
    window->display();
}

void Engine::MainLoop()
{
    //Loop until our window is closed
    while(window->isOpen())
    {
        ProcessInput();
        Update();
        RenderFrame();
    }
}

void Engine::Go()
{
    if(!Init())
        throw "Could not initialize Engine";
    MainLoop();
}
```

And here is the TextureManager.cpp

```
#include "TextureManager.h"
#include <vector>
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

TextureManager::TextureManager()
{

}

TextureManager::~TextureManager()
{

}

void TextureManager::AddTexture(sf::Texture& texture)
{
    textureList.push_back(texture);
}

sf::Texture& TextureManager::GetTexture(int index)
{
    return textureList[index];
}
```

In the tutorial itself the `Image` type was used but there was no `Draw()` method for `Image` so I made `Texture` instead. Why won't the `Texture` render on the screen?

Comment: No solution was found to this issue yet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in:

```
void Engine::LoadTextures()
{
    sf::Texture sprite;
    sprite.loadFromFile("C:\\Users\\Vipar\\Pictures\\sprite1.png");
    textureManager.AddTexture(sprite);
    testTile = new Tile(textureManager.GetTexture(0));
}
```

You are creating a local `sf::Texture` and passing that to `TextureManager::AddTexture`. It's probably going out of scope at the end of the function, and is then no longer valid when you try to draw it. You fix this by using a smart pointer:

```
void Engine::LoadTextures()
{
    textureManager.AddTexture(std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture>(
        new sf::Texture("C:\\Users\\Vipar\\Pictures\\sprite1.png")));

    testTile = new Tile(textureManager.GetTexture(0));
}
```

And changing `TextureManager` to use it:

```
void TextureManager::AddTexture(std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture> texture)
{
    textureList.push_back(texture);
}

sf::Texture& TextureManager::GetTexture(int index)
{
    return *textureList[index];
}
```

You'll also have to change `textureList` to be an `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture>` of course.

Comment: What would you propose for a solution? Making the sprite global wouldn't be very efficient at all. The idea is to pass by reference I think so that we just keep references to pictures and not millions of objects with the information.

Comment: I think the best way is probably to use a pointer and pass that around. You'll have to take care of cleanup then though. (I think smart pointers can help with that, but haven't played with them yet so not sure.)

Comment: Could you give me an example of how you would do that in your answer maybe? I am still a bit green :)

Comment: There put it in :) Sorry I took a while, wasn't checking SO and then took another 10 min to figure out smart pointers.

Comment: std:: doesn't have a shared_ptr member.

Comment: You'll have to `#include <memory>`. Also [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) is nice for quickly checking stuff like that ;)

Comment: Error: class "sf::Texture" has no member "get".

Comment: If you had changed `textureList` to `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture>>` it wouldn't say that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30509/discussion-between-vipar-and-mwerschy)